# Open specific links in specific browsers

Tags: macos, safari, google-chrome, web-browser

Is it possible to tell OS X to always open one site in Chrome, and always open another site in Safari?

In a nutshell, I want to set a default browser per domain rather than globally for the entire computer.

Here's why I ask:  Out of the box OS X does not come with Flash.  The Chrome browser has Flash bundled, however.  So I'd like to have domains that I know require Flash always open in Chrome, but everything else open in my preferred browser, which is Safari.

I'm okay with maintaining a "white list" of which sites need the "use chrome" exception, but right now I can't see any way to make it happen.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use [Choosy](https://www.choosyosx.com/)
It can prompt you to select from the browsers on your Mac so you can decide which browser is right for a particular link.

:)

Answer (score 2):

If you would rather use a free and open source app you can use [Finicky](https://github.com/johnste/finicky).

Don't be intimidated by writing a configuration file for Finicky! If you need help you can use [Finicky Kickstart](https://finicky-kickstart.vercel.app) to do the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 0):

I made a free app called [Velja](https://sindresorhus.com/velja) to solve this problem. It also includes built-in handling of opening some URLs in their desktop apps and removing tracking parameters from URLs. You can find a comparison with Choosy [here](https://sindresorhus.com/velja#choosy).

Comment: This is your app which you are promoting.  See “[How Not to Be A Spammer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)” specifically the “over promotion” section