# Opening specific URL in a not-default browser no matter from where it's called from (without using Choosy app)

Tags: macos, applescript, system-settings, web-browser

I need a certain URL to be always opened in a browser that's not systems default browser. Problem is, that this should happen even if the URL is called automatically from within a hardcoded 3rd party app.

Answer [Force URL link to open with a specific browser](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/121980/force-url-link-to-open-with-a-specific-browser) on one hand is focussing on .webloc and .url files or is using "Open with …" menu item. On the other hand it is mentioning  [Choosy App](https://www.choosyosx.com/); same does this answer: [Open specific links in specific browsers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/234950/open-specific-links-in-specific-browsers).

How can this be accomplished with on-board resources like a script?

Comment: @Allan re-wrote question to distinguish from existing answers.

Comment: That question has also been asked and answered. See:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33621/how-can-i-associate-url-files-with-a-specific-browser-in-snow-leopard/44082#44082

Comment: What's wrong with Choosy?

Comment: Will this url always be the same?  Will it be used somewhere else?  Can you modify the app?

Comment: @historystamp Choosy is behind a paywall; the url will always be the same, it is not used somewhere else and I can't modify the app.

Comment: seems like to me you could write a small applescript app to masquerade as your default web browser and filter accordingly. basically duplicate what choosy does.